# setInterval pauses in android during scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, scroll, setinterval

I'm having an issue with setInterval on android 
Here is my ex

```
update_interval = setInterval(function ()

 { 
    timeUpdateEvent()

    }, 250);
```

When I'm srcolling on mobile screen, setInterval pause and It's won't run until im stop scrolling. Is there any way to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: Please post the full code.

Comment: I'm making an app that play audio and highlight the text when time is right, and using setInterval to check the time to highlight, and When I'm scrolling on andoird mobile then the function update_interval  pause until i'm stop scrolling. I'm using https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp it's work fine but i'm wonder. Is there anyway to fix the issue without using timeupdate event ?